# Working with python dictionary

Tags: python

How can I store multiple keys and values in school dictionary? 
I was trying to store a list of keys and values in a dictionary with a for loop but I did t know how to go about it. 
Can any one help me out?

Comment: Please show what you've attempted. As it is, there's no way for us to address your misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = ['a', 'b']
values = [1, 2]
print(dict(zip(keys,values)))
```

Output:

```
{'a':1,'b':2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
keys = ['bob', 'alice']
values = [40, 20]

d = {}

for i in range(len(keys)):
    d[keys[i]] = values[i]
```

Learn the basics of python dictionary and looping. You will find tons of resources in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = [1, 2, 3]
# First way
d1 = {k: v for k, v in zip(lst1, lst2)}
print d1
# {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

# Second way    
d2 = dict(zip(lst1, lst2))
print d2
# {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```